# Regarding typedefs of 1-element arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

Sometimes, in C, you do this:

```c
typedef struct foo {
   unsigned int some_data;
} foo; /* btw, foo_t is discouraged */
```

To use this new type in an OO-sort-of-way, you might have alloc/free pairs like these:

```c
foo *foo_alloc(/* various "constructor" params */);
void foo_free(foo *bar);
```

Or, alternatively init/clear pairs (perhaps returning error-codes):

```c
int foo_init(foo *bar, /* and various "constructor" params */);
int foo_clear(foo *bar);
```

I have seen the following idiom used, in particular in the MPFR library:

```c
struct foo {
   unsigned int some_data;
};
typedef struct foo foo[1]; /* <- notice, 1-element array */
typedef struct foo *foo_ptr; /* let's create a ptr-type */
```

The alloc/free and init/clear pairs now read:

```c
foo_ptr foo_alloc(/* various "constructor" params */);
void foo_free(foo_ptr bar);
int foo_init(foo_ptr bar, /* and various "constructor" params */);
int foo_clear(foo_ptr bar);
```

Now you can use it all like this (for instance, the init/clear pairs):

```c
int main()
{  
   foo bar; /* constructed but NOT initialized yet */
   foo_init(bar); /* initialize bar object, alloc stuff on heap, etc. */
   /* use bar */
   foo_clear(bar); /* clear bar object, free stuff on heap, etc. */
}
```

**Remarks**: The init/clear pair seems to allow for a more generic way of initializing and clearing out objects. Compared to the alloc/free pair, the init/clear pair requires that a "shallow" object has already been constructed. The "deep" construction is done using init.

**Question**: Are there any non-obvious pitfalls of the 1-element array "type-idiom"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is very clever (but see below).

It encourages the misleading idea that C function arguments can be passed by reference.

If I see this in a C program:

```
foo bar;
foo_init(bar);
```

I know that the call to `foo_init` does not modify the value of `bar`. I also know that the code passes the value of `bar` to a function when it hasn't initialized it, which is very probably undefined behavior.

*Unless* I happen to know that `foo` is a typedef for an array type. Then I suddenly realize that `foo_init(bar)` is not passing the *value* of `bar`, but the address of its first element. And now every time I see something that refers to type `foo`, or to an object of type `foo`, I have to think about how `foo` was defined as a typedef for a single-element array before I can understand the code.

It is an attempt to make C look like something it's not, not unlike things like:

```
#define BEGIN {
#define END }
```

and so forth. And it doesn't result in code that's easier to understand because it uses features that C doesn't support directly. It results in code that's *harder* to understand (*especially* to readers who know C well), because you have to understand both the customized declarations *and* the underlying C semantics that make the whole thing work.

If you want to pass pointers around, just pass pointers around, and do it explicitly. See, for example, the use of `FILE*` in the various standard functions defined in `<stdio.h>`. There is no attempt to hide pointers behind macros or typedefs, and C programmers have been using that interface for decades.

If you want to write code that looks like it's passing arguments by reference, define some function-like macros, and give them all-caps names so knowledgeable readers will know that something odd is going on.

I said above that this is "clever". I'm reminded of something I did when I was first learning the C language:

```
#define EVER ;;
```

which let me write an infinite loop as:

```
for (EVER) {
    /* ... */
}
```

At the time, I thought it was clever.

I still think it's clever. I just no longer think that's a good thing.

Comment: Interestingly, this question was born out of the same likely frustration that you mention. Namely, that as a user of the object type Foo, you would probably need to understand the underlying typedef definition. I was trying to use the MPFR library, and was confused because of this. But I forgot that - and I found it clever only because it took a long time for me to understand it :-) In that library, it might make a bit more sense, since you would need to easily create and initialize small objects (numbers) on the stack. But more fancy (clever) stuff gets tricky.

Comment: Nice one, Keith! It was very much a pleasure reading your answer. SO needs more answers, like this one, that have flair, style, and extras like fun personal memories which give the reader more than a mere answer.

Answer (score 3):

The only advantage to this method is nicer looking code and easier typing. It allows the user to create the struct on the stack without dynamic allocation like so:

```
foo bar;
```

However, the structure can still be passed to functions that require a pointer type, without requiring the user to convert to a pointer with `&bar` every time.

```
foo_init(bar);
```

Without the 1 element array, it would require either an alloc function as you mentioned, or constant `&` usage.

```
foo_init(&bar);
```

The only pitfall I can think of is the normal concerns associated with direct stack allocation. If this in a library used by other code, updates to the struct may break client code in the future, which would not happen when using an alloc free pair.

Comment: Exactly - that's my view on it too. It makes notation a bit simpler.

Comment: And also less obvious as it decreases readability, and breaks our internal parsers (brains). Please **do not do this.**

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree, sticking with standard language syntax and usage is usually best even if it involves a little more typing.

Comment: But `typedef struct Foo Foo;` seems to be rather accepted? We can see it, rather simplified, as removing the word "struct" from the type name. Other uses of `typedef` that hides specific language features (such as use of arrays) should probably be discouraged.